# jQuery - How to add HTML 5 data attributes into the DOM

Tags: jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I am trying to add a HTML 5 data attribute into the DOM. I have seen on the jQuery site the format for data attributes is:

```
$('.pane-field-related-pages ul').data("role") === "listview";
```

But this doesnt seem to add anything into the DOM?

How can I add the above data-role into the related ul tag?

Comment: The Strict comparison operator === is not for setting data, it's for checking if the two strings are strictly equal (same sequence of characters, same length, and same characters in corresponding positions)

You need to use the notation as provided by diEcho to SET attributes

Answer (score 18):

Read [this article](http://www.queness.com/post/7050/8-jquery-methods-you-need-to-know)

From article

---

> jQuery.com - "The .data() method
>   allows us to attach data of any type
>   to DOM elements in a way that is safe
>   from circular references and therefore
>   from memory leaks."
>
> With the introduction of HTML5, we can
>   use it as attribute as well. For
>   example

```
<div data-role="page" data-hidden="true" data-options='{"name":"John"}'></div>


//We can call it via:
$("div").data("role") = "page";
$("div").data("hidden") = true;
$("div").data("options").name = "John";
```

#### alternate way

```
$("div").data("role", "page");
$("div").data("hidden", "true");
$("div").data("role", {name: "John"});
```

Comment: You're checking on equality, not doing an assignment. Same issue for the OP

Comment: @diEcho I edited your answer because it took me some time to understand what's going on when I was reading the original version. Hope you'll like my edits.

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation for .data() in the Jquery API, you need to do this to set it:

```
$('.pane-field-related-pages ul').data("role", "listview");
```

And this to check it:

```
$('.pane-field-related-pages ul').data("role");
```

Answer (score 2):

In complement to diEcho response you have 2 data() methods in jQuery.

The first one is detailled in @diEcho response, you apply [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to a jQuery selection, it's a getter with one arguiment and a setter with more than one argument.

The second method is [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/), applied directly to jQuery. It takes one more argument in first position, the DOM element (if you have a jQuery selection do a get(0) you get the DOM element).